# Automatically set ggsave width argument in lapply based on number of observations in dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggsave

Let's say I have a list of dataframe and I want to plot them one by one using `lapply` and `geom_tile`, and `ggsave` it locally to my computer:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df1 <- data.frame(grp = rep("A", 30), 
                  point = 1:30, 
                  y = rep(1, 30), 
                  var = sample(c(T, F), 30, replace = T))

df2 <- data.frame(grp = rep("B", 100), 
                  point = 1:100, 
                  y = rep(1, 100), 
                  var = sample(c(T, F), 100, replace = T))

df_list <- list(df1, df2)

# this should save "A.png" and "B.png" to the current directory
lapply(df_list, function(x) {
  p <- ggplot(x, aes(point, y, fill = var)) + geom_tile(color = "black") + theme_minimal()
  ggsave(filename = paste0(unique(x[["grp"]]), ".png"), plot = p, width = 8, height = 3)
  })
```

Normally, setting `ggsave(width = 8)` is perfect for most of the dataframes, but for some of them, they have unusually large number of observations that `width = 8` will be too crowded.

For example, `df1` (A.png) is fine with `width = 8`:

[image: df1]

However, `df2` (B.png) might be too crowded:

[image: df2]

For example, in `df2`, I would like to save it with `ggsave(width = 25)`.

[image: df2_width25]

Is there a way to change the `ggsave(width)` argument **automatically** based on the number of observations in the dataframe that we are plotting to obtain an **optimally scaled** plot (e.g. if the dataframe has more than 100 datapoints, `width` should be greater than 25, and I'd like it to scale automatically)?

I know it's very hard to define **optimally scaled**, but the point here is to find a way to have different `ggsave(width)` in each `lapply` iteration.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use an `ifelse` or `case_when` statement to set the width based on `nrow()`.

```
lapply(df_list, function(x) {
    p <- ggplot(x, aes(point, y, fill = var)) + 
      geom_tile(color = "black") + 
      theme_minimal()
    ggsave(filename = paste0(unique(x[["grp"]]), ".png"), 
           plot = p, 
           width = ifelse(nrow(x) > 80, 25, 4), 
           height = 3)
    })
```